# Python class's init function takes instance of own class as default parameter

Tags: python, class, parameters, default, init

I'm trying to define a class which takes in a default parameter for its init function. I've defined a class as follows:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,name,visited=False,distance=math.inf,path=Node('-')):
        self.name = name
        self.visited = visited
        self.distance = distance
        self.path = path
```

and I get the following error:

> NameError: name 'Node' is not defined

I was able to get around this problem by "pre-defining" the parts of the class that I needed, like so:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class Node:
    def __init__(self,name,visited=False,distance=math.inf,path=Node('-')):
        self.name = name
        self.visited = visited
        self.distance = distance
        self.path = path
```

but I can't shake the feeling there's a better, more pythonic way.

Comment: Why is class taking itself as a parameter?

Comment: I'm writing an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm, and each node needs to be able to point to another node.

Comment: What should the `path` be for the `Node` object you'd be setting as the default?

Comment: @Blckknght I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Each ```Node``` points to another ```Node```, and if it doesn't currently point to another ```Node``` in the graph it should point to a dummy ```Node``` (e.g. '-').

Comment: Sure, but does the dummy node point to itself, or to some *other* `Node` object? What does the first `Node` to ever exist point to, when there don't exist any other `Node`s yet?

Comment: I see what you're getting at after reading through juanpa's answer. I've accepted his 'default-path' solution.

Comment: If you want to, you could have a single dummy `Node` object. And if you wanted, it could link to itself with its `path` attribute. But you'd have to set all that up *after* the class gets defined, not before.

Comment: Another alternative is just to use a sentinel object as the default value for that Node, even just `SENTINEL = object()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, visited=False, distance=math.inf, path=None):
        self.name = name
        self.visited = visited
        self.distance = distance
        if path is None:
            self.path = Node('-', path="default-path")
        else:
            self.path = path
```

This is the idiom you should be following with mutable default arguments to begin with.

However, you need the default to have a path, or it will recurse without stopping.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this recurses forever, since the new node you create needs a `path` value of its own.

Comment: @Blckknght yes, yes